# Sum of two continuous random variables

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-probability, density-function, uniform-distribution

Let **R1** and **R2** be two independent random variables, both with uniform density at the interval (0,2).

What is the probability of **R1>1** given that **R1 +R2<2**?

--

What I've tried:
I know that
$$
P(R1>1/R1+R2<2)= \frac{P(R1 +R2<2 ∩ R1>1)}{P(R1 +R2<2)}$$
And I know that **P(R1>1)=1/2** and **P(R1 +R2<2)=1/2**

How can I find the intersection?

Comment: You would need more information on the joint distribution of $X_1, X_2$ than that. Are they independent? If so, are they uniform?

Comment: Are they perhaps independent and identically distributed?

Comment: They are uniform and independent. I edited

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to find $p=P(R_1+R_2<2\cap R_1>1)$. The joint distribution is $1/4$ in $[0,2]\times [0,2]$, and the probability of interest here is a triangular region between $x+y=2$,$y=0$,$x=1$, which has an area of $1/2$. So, $p=(1/2)\times(1/4)=1/8$.

$$P(R_1>1|R_1+R_2<2)=\frac{1/8}{1/2}=1/4$$

Comment: How do I find the joint distribution?

Comment: @Oalvinegro Since they're independent, it is the multiplication of marginals, i.e. $1/2\times 1/2$